# Why might pasting an URL link into iCloud from a PC make that link inactive on iOS in notes?

Tags: iphone, icloud, notes.app

If I paste a link/URL into the notes app from my iPhone, it works fine, I can tap on it and have it open in Safari.

When I try to paste a link from my Windows computer, via icloud.com, the note shows up fine on my phone, but when I tap a link, nothing happens (it highlights briefly).

In this case, I am forced to copy and paste the link into Safari manually.

I'm pasting from a Windows 7 computer running Chrome. The link **does** appear, underline and everything. It's as if iOS knows its a URL but refuses to open it.

Comment: I don't have a PC to test this, but are you pasting in structured text or plain text into the note from the PC. What browser are you using to access iCloud.com from the PC. Can you edit the text of the link (perhaps deleting a t in http and then placing it back to see if iOS detects the URL upon an edit)? Is adding white space after the URL enough to bump the link detection?

Comment: @bmike - Added more info to my question about the OS and browser.

Answer (score 1):

I made a short clip of how the web app works when typing.

My guess is the paste event isn't triggering the URL detection and I can replicate the behavior you describe on Safari by pasting in and matching the style - even when I cut the URL that was detected by my typing.

All I need to to is add a space after the paste event and the URL gets encoded properly and turns blue as shown in [this short video](http://cl.ly/LXl1)...

So, you need to type a space to get the paste to be processed.

Comment: You're typing. I'm talking about pasting.

Comment: Yup - psating doesn't trigger the detection properly, so it's either as designed or a bug. typing is a workaround. Perhaps I should have added that more explicitly to the answer.

Comment: I can't type out long URLs, so its not really a fix:(

Comment: Paste then type one space after the paste works for me..

Comment: It turns blue, but it still won't open properly on iOS.

Comment: Has anyone been able to get hyperlinks to actually open in icloud notes?

Comment: @word2u You can't directly click links in Notes app on Mavericks or in the new iCloud notes app, but you can control click and then open the URL from there.